# Relation between an increasing function and its Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have recently been trying some questions on Riemann integral. Got stuck in one of the problems which says:

Suppose $f$ is an increasing real-valued function on [$0$,$\infty$] with $f$($x$) $\gt$ $0$ for all $x$ and let $g$($x$)=$\frac{1}{x}$$\int_{0}^{x}f(u)du$ where $0$  $\lt x\lt$ $\infty$.

Then $g$($x$) $\le$ $f$($x$) for all $x$ in ($0,\infty$).

How to show this?

I can show that $g$($x$) $\gt$ $0$ but unable to show the above relation.

Help, please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ x>0$.

$ f $ is increasing at $ [0,x]  \;\;\implies$

$$(\forall u\in[0,x]) \;\; f(u)\le f(x) \;\;\implies $$

$$\int_0^xf(u)du\le \int_0^xf(x)du \;\; \implies$$

$$\int_0^xf(u)du\le f(x)(x-0)\;\; \implies$$

$$g(x)\le f(x)$$

We used the fact that a monotonic function at $ [a,b] $ is Riemann-integrable at $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you so much